# How much fuel remains in a booster such as the one used for Jason-3

Tags: spacex, landing, fuel, reuse, booster-flyback

Building off of [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/what-started-the-explosion-on-the-crashed-jason-3-stage-on-the-barge), I am curious as to **how much (just a simple magnitude of order) propellant remains inside a booster to cause such an explosion**?  Considering cost, I would expect very little would have remained after main engine cutoff on the barge, preventing such a hollywood-style explosion.

Comment: Fuel is cheap, relative to the value of the rocket stage. They want to have a margin to make sure they don't run out of propellant just before the landing. And don't underestimate the explosive power of fuel. 100 litres of RP-1 plus the same in LOX is in the same ballpark as a 250-lb air-launched bomb.

Comment: The explosion on Jason 3 was actually very small — compare it to the CRS 6 barging attempt. Also, having excess fuel actually makes landing _simpler_ as the landing velocity/deceleration is smaller

Comment: The explosion doesn't come from the liquid propellant. That would just burn - really fiercely in the presence of liquid oxygen, but it doesn't explode. The fuel vapor (of which there is probably a lot) on the other hand, will go bang if it's mixed with oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a quote to source it, but recall Elon Musk saying it was on the order of a 100 lbs of fuel and oxidizer left. Almost dry, but clearly enough to burn.